# How to populate fields in html from database using Entity Framework in a console Application?

Tags: c#, html, mysql, entity-framework-6

I created a html file which I'm going to use to generate a PDF form using SelectPDF. This HTML has text fields, checkboxes that need to be filled/checked with data from my MySQL database. I want to use `c#` to communicate with my database so I'm using Entity Framework. The idea is for the console Application to run, grab the info from the database, populate the fields in the html file and the program generate a PDF from it. Up to now, the HTML to PDF part works as intended.

What I don't know, is how to pass data from my tables in the database to my simple HTML file, since I am not using Razor pages/ASPX files.

How could I go about it with my Entity Framework models?

At the moment, I'm using a small database with 5 tables for testing - the real database  has 20+ tables.

[Example of PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq3Z8.png)

[image: img1]

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6PIx.png)

[image: img2]

Program.cs code:

```
//assign html file to string, add directory location of file.
string HtmlString = (@"C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\IIAForm30.html");

    // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

/*********************************************************
 *                                                       *
 *                                                       *
 *                      PDF Settings                     *      
 *                                                       *
 *                                                       *
 * *******************************************************/

//set PDF page size 
//supports:(A0 to A10),(B0 to B5),(ArchA to ArchE),(Letter, HalfLetter, Letter11x17, Note, Flsa, Ledger)
converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;

//set PDF page orientation
//Supports Landscape and Portrait
converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;


//ShrinkOnly: the html content is resized only if the content width is 
//larger than the destination space (pdf page or rectangle) width. 
converter.Options.AutoFitWidth = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.ShrinkOnly;

// NoAdjustment: the html content is not resized vertically in any way to fit the available space. 
//If the content is larger, it will be cut and not all of it will be displayed in the generated pdf file.
converter.Options.AutoFitHeight = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.NoAdjustment;

// header settings
converter.Options.DisplayHeader = true;
converter.Header.DisplayOnFirstPage = false;
converter.Header.DisplayOnOddPages = true;
converter.Header.DisplayOnEvenPages = true;
converter.Header.Height = 20;

//Page Layout
//SinglePage: Displays one page at a time when open.
converter.Options.ViewerPreferences.PageLayout = PdfViewerPageLayout.SinglePage;

//converts html to pdf.
PdfDocument doc1 = converter.ConvertUrl(HtmlString);
PdfDocument doc2 = converter.ConvertUrl(HtmlString);
PdfDocument doc3 = converter.ConvertUrl(HtmlString);

// save pdf document
doc1.Save("Sample1.pdf");
doc2.Save("Sample2.pdf");
doc3.Save("Sample3.pdf");

// create a new pdf document
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

// add the pages of these documents to the new document
doc.Append(doc1);
doc.Append(doc2);
doc.Append(doc3);

// save pdf document
doc.Save("MergedDoc.pdf");

// close pdf document
doc.Close();

// close the original pdf documents
doc1.Close();
doc2.Close();
doc3.Close();

//original pdf files are discarded/deleted
File.Delete("Sample1.pdf");
File.Delete("Sample2.pdf");
File.Delete("Sample3.pdf");
```

HTML snippet for context (only using plain text to occupy the position where the database date would go):

```html
<table class="tg-3" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
 <colgroup>
  <col style="width: 130px">
  <col style="width: 120px">
  <col style="width: 120px">
  <col style="width: 110px">
  <col style="width: 100px">
  <col style="width: 100px">
  <col style="width: 150px">
 </colgroup>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg-576q" colspan="7" style="border-top: none;">I. Inspector Information</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg-r0wx" style="border-bottom: none;">Date of Inspection</td>
  <td class="tg-es7u" style="border-bottom: none;border-right: none;">Inspected by:</td>
  <td class="tg-9vem" rowspan="3" style="border-right: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;">John Doe</td>
  <td class="tg-r0wx" style="border-bottom: none; border-right: none;border-left: none;"></td>
  <td class="tg-9vem" rowspan="3" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">Inspector</td>
  <td class="tg-es7u" style="border-left: none;border-right: none;border-bottom: none;"></td>
  <td class="tg-9vem" rowspan="3" style="border-left: none;">(777)777-7777</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg-9vem" rowspan="1" style="border-top: none; border-right-style: solid;border-bottom: none; text-align: right">2018-02-03</td>
  <td class="tg-es7u" rowspan="2" style="border-right: none;border-top: none; border-left-style: solid;">Name:</td>
  <td class="tg-es7u" rowspan="2" style="border-top: none; border-right: none; border-left: none;">Title:</td>
  <td class="tg-es7u" rowspan="2" style="border-left: none; border-top: none; border-right: none;">Phone Number:</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="1" style="border-top: none"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg-r0wx" colspan="3" style="border-bottom: none;">Inspection Company</td>
  <td class="tg-es7u" colspan="1" rowspan="3" style="border-right: none;">Inspector Signature:</td>
  <td class="tg-n603" colspan="3" rowspan="3" style="border-left: none;"><img src="signatureStock.PNG" width="180" height="50"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg-tnbn" colspan="3" rowspan="1" style="border-top: none;">John Doe Company</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To get the best answers to questions on stack overflow it is usually best to try and condense your problem down to the smallest piece of broken code you can. Open ended questions or large problems spaces usually don't get much attention.

Comment: To be very honest, i don't know how i could have ask this question in a more specific way. But it is true what you said, i'll keep it in mind when posting any future questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome. I would suggest you take a look at the library:

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

It's a way of being able to generate HTML from templates, being passed models. It's very similar to the Razor library used for ASP.NET MVC, but doesn't need to be used in a web project.

I would replace your hardcoded HTML path, with a local template, get the data from the DB using Entity Framework, pass that as the model into the template, then render the template output as a PDF. Voila.

Comment: Thank you @tigerswithguitars, it seems your suggestion is what i need. 
But i'm having trouble understanding how to run it, the documentation is really hard to understand can't seem to find a full example on how to use it. 
I created _Pdf.cshtml and added a snippet from my html code to test it out.  How would the code go for me to get the output from this view so i can then generate the pdf?  
Note: SelectPDF is the library i'm using and can only generate a pdf using direct html code/url.

Comment: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/387 this might help you understand how to load your templates and then use them.